# Different color per dataset

Tags: colors, indexing, gnuplot

After 2 days of trials and errors, I ask for help here since I am totally lost with gnuplot.
All I want is to display a few datasets in different colors, with named columns.
Here is the result:

[image: result]

First problem: lines on the graph have different colors but in the title colors are the same.
2nd problem: If I replace "idx" after the plotline by column(-2) (ie:

```
datafile index idx using "packetid":'mapping_dsn':(0):"mapping_length":(column(-2)) with vectors filled head size screen 0.008,145 lc palette z title sprintf("dataset %d", column(-2))
```

I've got this output

[image: second result]

In my opinion idx and column(-2) should be equivalent?
Here is a shortened version of the gnuplot script (most critical parts I believe):

```
stats datafile every ::2
set palette maxcolors 3
set palette defined ( 0 'green', \
                      1 'red', \
                      2 'blue' )

set key autotitle columnhead
set cbrange[0:STATS_blocks-1]

plot for [idx=0:STATS_blocks-1] \
    datafile index idx using "packetid":'mapping_dsn':(0):"mapping_length":(idx) with vectors filled head size screen 0.008,145 lc palette z title sprintf("dataset %d", idx)
```

My data format consists of 2 datasets and looks like this (I've removed some data to make it shorter):

```
packetid|time_delta|ip4src|ip4dst|ip6src|ip6dst|mptcpstream|tcpstream|subtype|tcpseq|mapping_ssn|mapping_length|mapping_dsn|ssn_to_dsn|dataack
2|0.000000000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|0|0|||||
5|0.000067000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|2|1|1|20|0||
6|0.000125000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|2|21|21|20|20||
8|0.000064000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|2|41|41|20|40||
9|0.000125000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|2|61|61|20|60||

packetid|time_delta|ip4src|ip4dst|ip6src|ip6dst|mptcpstream|tcpstream|subtype|tcpseq|mapping_ssn|mapping_length|mapping_dsn|ssn_to_dsn|dataack
2|0.000000000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|0|0|||||
5|0.000067000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|2|1|1|20|0||
6|0.000125000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|2|21|21|20|20||
8|0.000064000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|2|41|41|20|40||
9|0.000125000|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2|||0|0|2|61|61|20|60||
```

**EDIT after message** from christophe: I still have a problem though after modifying according to your a dvice (linetype 0 does not exist so I reindexed a bit):

```
set linetype 1 lw 3 pt 3 lc rgb "red"
set linetype 2 lw 3 pt 3 lc rgb "green"

... datafile index idx using "packetid":'mapping_dsn':(0):"mapping_length":(idx+1) with vectors filled head size screen 0.008,145 lc variable title sprintf("Mappings from dataset %d", idx)
```

Title arrows are all in black (instead of red and green):
[image: 3rd result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the `linecolor palette` (and also with `linecolor variable`) approach is, that the linecolor can vary for a single plot. Gnuplot doesn't consider the special case when the color specification is constant for all points.

To have the correct keys, you must use `lc idx` with the loop index `idx`:

```
plot for [idx=0:STATS_blocks-1] \
datafile index idx using "packetid":'mapping_dsn':(0):"mapping_length" with vectors filled head size screen 0.008,145 lc idx+1 title sprintf("dataset %d", idx)
```

Concerning `column(-2)` vs `idx`: Using `column(-2)` outside of the `using` statement doesn't work properly. I my opinion it should give an error when doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments that provide 2 pieces of information I never found elsewhere and don't think I would have. I still have  a problem though after modifying according to your advice. See Edit in first post

Comment: Ups, sorry. Of course, `lc variable` has the same problem like `lc palette`, the line color could vary in a single plot. Since you're looping anyway, use `lt idx` instead. I'll update the answer in a moment.