# gnuplot key generating issue

Tags: key, gnuplot, legend, dynamically-generated

I have a file format like this:

```
2014/3/12 18:02:36 1 SSID1
2014/3/12 18:02:37 1 SSID1
2014/3/12 18:02:38 2 SSID2
2014/3/12 18:02:39 1 SSID1
2014/3/12 18:02:39 3 SSID3
2014/3/12 18:02:39 3 SSID3
2014/3/12 18:02:39 2 SSID2
```

I create a gnuplot script to plot with a calendar scheme -> date in X and hours in Y with points for every connexion to an SSID). I use a lc variable to generate different color from column(3).

```
reset
clear

file_exists(file) = system("[ -f '".file."' ] && echo '1' || echo '0'") + 0


fontsize(x)=((GPVAL_TERM eq 'postscript') && \
    (strstrt(GPVAL_TERMOPTIONS,"eps")!=0)) ? x*2 : x

set xdata time
set ydata time

set timefmt x "%Y/%m/%d"
set timefmt y "%H:%M:%S"

day = 360*24
set xtics 70*day

set format y "%H"
set format x "%B %d"

set ylabel "Time (Hour)"
set xlabel "Date (Month Day)" offset -1,0

set xlabel font 'Arial-Bold, 15"
set ylabel font 'Arial-Bold, 15"

set xtics rotate
set xtics font "Arial-bold, 15"
set ytics font "Arial-Bold, 15"

set style data points

set terminal png size 3200,2400

do for [i=2:2] {

  if ( file_exists("data".i.".dat") ) {

    set output sprintf("%s.png", "data".i)

    set key box below

    set title "Different SSID Wifi on color"

    plot "data".i.".dat" using 1:2:3 linecolor variable pt 7 ps 1 t columnhead(4)

   }

}
```

But I can't have a correct legend (key). With my code, I just have a box with the first SSID on the column(4), with the correct color ... but how I can have all SSID in this box with all variable color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `title columnheader(4)` you select the fourth column of the first row as key title for the whole plot. To get the correct title, and also the correct line colors in the key (see e.g. [Different color per dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27901349/2604213) concerning key colors with `linecolor variable`) its best to generate a list containing all unique SSIDs and then iterate over them:

```
file = 'data2.dat'
SSIDs = system(sprintf('awk ''{print $4}'' %s | sort | uniq', file))

set xdata time
set ydata time

set timefmt x "%Y/%m/%d"
set timefmt y "%H:%M:%S"

day = 360*24
set xtics 70*day

set format y "%H"
set format x "%B %d"

set style data points

plot for [s=1:words(SSIDs)] file using (strcol(4) eq word(SSIDs, s) ? timecolumn(1) : 1/0):2:3 lc s pt 7 ps 1 t word(SSIDs, s)
```

Note, that using this `1/0` trick works fine when plotting `with points`. If, for some reason you want to plot lines, you must do the filtering using e.g. `grep`:

```
cmd(s, f) = sprintf('< grep ''%s'' %s', s, f)
plot for [s=1:words(SSIDs)] cmd(s, file) using 1:2:3 lc s pt 7 ps 1 t word(SSIDs, s)
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. It works almost ... With the trick 1/0, I have a problem like this : Warning: empty x range [2014:2014], adjusting to [1993.86:2034.14] ... I tried some changes but not succeed but i can see that label and color are correctly assigned just x axis is not working well ...

Comment: That can happen if you have an autoscaled xrange, but only a single date in your file.

Comment: Ok. I had more date in my file and add some range for x and y : 
set xrange ["2014/3/12":"2014/9/12"]
set yrange ["00:00:00":"23:59:59"]
Now no error during running, I have a .png with the good range, the good key but no point ...

Comment: Sorry, couldn't test it when I posted. No need to set an explicit range, you must only use `timecolumn(1)` instead of `$1`, then it works (tested now with 4.6.5).